# Evitar registros duplicados en C# y PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

Hola compañeros tengo un formulario donde registro a los miembros de un club pero quisiera que al insertar un registro me lo rechace si ya existe y si no existe que lo inserte, este es mi codigo.

```
                NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;PORT=5432;UID=postgres;PWD=1234;DATABASE=Proyecto;");
                cn.Open();

                NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO miembros (idmiembro,nombre,apellidos,sexo,grupo,fecha_nacimiento,domicilio,status)" + "VALUES ('" + txtId.Text + "','" + txtNombre.Text + "','"
                + txtApellidos.Text + "','" + txtSexo.Text + "','" + txtGrupo.Text + "' ,'" + txtNacimiento.Text + "' ,'" + txtDomicilio.Text + "' ,'" + txtStatus.Text + "')", cn);
                    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Miembro registrado exitosamente");
                    txtId.Text = "";
                    txtNombre.Text = "";
                    txtApellidos.Text = "";
                    txtSexo.Text = "";
                    txtGrupo.Text = "";
                    txtNacimiento.Text = "";
                    txtDomicilio.Text = "";
                    txtStatus.Text = "";
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es crear una consulta que te diga si el IdMiembro existe. Si existe, mandas un mensaje de error, de lo contrario, guardas los cambios. (Aclaro que es una solución rápida)

Comment: Otra podría ser crar una función en la base de datos que guarde el nuevo miembro. Antes de guardar se fija si existe. Devolvés true o falso dependiendo de si existía o no. Desde el código captas el valor de la función y podrías lanzar una excepción si la funcion te devuelve falso. Si la idea te interesa te ayudo a armar algo...

Comment: si me interesa la idea podrias ayudarme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen dos maneras de resolver el problema que indicas:

1. A nivel de aplicación. Es decir, en tu aplicación (en este caso, usando C#) creas una función/método que busque si el usuario existe en la base de datos. En caso de no existir, lo registra. El método puede ser tan simple como ejecutar este query:

   ```sql
   -- buena práctica, en Postgres es mejor usar COUNT(1)
   -- que COUNT(*), el primero solo cuenta 1 elemento por fila
   -- mientras que COUNT(*) traerá todos los elementos de la fila
   -- para contarlos como 1, lo cual hace que COUNT(1) sea más rápido
   SELECT COUNT(1) FROM miembros WHERE <condición de único>
   ```

   Entonces puedes ejecutar este query desde tu aplicación antes de registrar el valor. El código luciría como:

   ```
   //buena práctica: las cadenas que vas a reutilizar en múltiples lugares
   //deberían ser escritas como constantes en tu clase
   const string CADENA_CONEXION = "SERVER=localhost;PORT=5432;UID=postgres;PWD=1234;DATABASE=Proyecto;";

   //buena práctica: encapsula la información en clases
   //y usa objetos para interactuar entre las capas de
   //tu aplicación
   public boolean existeMiembro(Miembro miembro)
   {
       Int64 contador = 0;
       try
       {
           NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection(CADENA_CONEXION);
           cn.Open();
           //buena práctica: usa parámetros en tus consultas
           NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM miembros WHERE id = @id");
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", miembro.Id);
           contador = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
           cn.Close();
       } catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //maneja la excepción
       }
       return contador > 0;
   }

   public void registraMiembro(Miembro miembro)
   {
       if (!existeMiembro(miembro))
       {
           try
           {
               //resto de tu código
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Nota: esto implica que en lugar de trabajar directamente con los campos de tu formulario, registres toda esa información en un objeto de la clase `Miembro` y luego llames a tu método `registraMiembro` con este objeto `Miembro`. Esto va a facilitar más el mantenimiento de tu aplicación.

   Esta solución es buena cuando tu aplicación solo la usa un usuario a la vez. Si múltiples usuarios pueden usar tu aplicación y registrar a un mismo `Miembro` al mismo tiempo, entonces esta solución se queda corta y de todas maneras tendrás registros duplicados. Para resolver ese problema, la siguiente alternativa.
2. Crea un índice único en tu tabla en base de datos. En Postgres, esto se logra con la siguiente sentencia:

   ```sql
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX miembro_id_unico ON miembros (id);
   ```

   Con eso, cuando se inserte un registro con el mismo id, la base de datos va a lanzar una excepción:

   > ERROR duplicate key value violates unique constraint "miembro_id_unico"

Comment: Lo de `count(1)` siendo mejor que `count(*)` es un mito que se repite a menudo, pero no tiene base.

Comment: @sstan no es un mito, me ha pasado en pruebas de concepto de servicios REST con una aplicación apuntando a Postgres al medir el tiempo con JMeter, el `COUNT(1)` se demoraba mucho menos que el `COUNT(*)` sobretodo para tablas con más de 20 campos donde la ejecución del `SELECT` era relativamente sencilla.

Comment: Ahora me picastes la curiosidad. Y como es un tema que me interesa bastante, voy a verificar. Si tienes algun ejemplo reproducible, me interesaría mucho.

Comment: De uno de los devs (Tom Lane) de PostgreSQL, y esto fue hace tiempo, y no creo que haya empeorado desde entonces: http://pgsql-sql.postgresql.narkive.com/s3Nf6xB5/performance-difference-in-count-1-vs-count

Comment: Me baso en los resultados de mis pruebas. La práctica es más real que la teoría :|

Comment: Pues estuve haciendo pruebas con tablas de 20 columnas y millones de registros, y en todos los casos `select count(*)` y `select count(1)` tienen el mismo plan de ejecución y un rendimiento idéntico. En mi caso, la teoría y la práctica siempre han concordado. Lo más probable es que lo que te sucedió tiene otra explicación. Por eso, si tienes algún script que muestre lo contrario, te lo agradecería. Disculpa la insistencia, pero me apasiona el tema de las bases de datos, y me importa que la información al respecto sea correcta. Estoy seguro que te sientes igual con Java por ejemplo.

Comment: la aplicación sera utilizada para muchos usuarios pero cada uno registrara diferentes usuarios, entonces me sirve la opción 1? y aun así puedo utilizar la sentencia de UNIQUE?

Comment: Si puede darse el caso que dos personas usando la aplicación puedan registrar al mismo usuario, entonces la opción 1 va a fallar. Lo mejor sería usar la opción 2.

Comment: +1 solo por la opción 2. La 1 no sirve para operaciones en paralelo.

Comment: @PabloClaus tal como dice al final de la opción 1 :)

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Podrías preguntar primero en la base de datos si el registro que vas a insertar existe, si existe te manda un mensaje que ya se encuentra registrado de lo contrario das de alta a un nuevo mienbro.

```
public static bool Exist(string name)
    {
        using (var cn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clientes WHERE RazonSocial=?name";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", name);

                var count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Aplicas la validación:

```
bool exist = ClienteRepository.Exist(entity.RazonSocial);
            if(exist)
                throw new ArgumentException("El Cliente, que intenta registrar ya existe.");
            else
            {
                ClienteRepository.Create(entity);
            }
```

Este es un código de ejemplo, debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: oye porque me marca error en ConfigurationManager

Comment: @karolprincess Tines que agregar la referencia al proyecto system configuration y despues agregar el espacio de nombre Using Configuration http://mouse-puntonet.blogspot.pe/2011/03/agregarquitar-referencias-en-visual.html

Comment: ya lo agregue y lo agregue al espacio de nombre y me dice que no existe

Comment: @karolprincess lo vemos por el chat

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una consulta que primero actualize, si el resultado no generó ninguna fila afectada entonces no existe.
Entonces procedes a insertar el registro.

ojala este ejemplo te ayude:

```
update STEVNTF 
            set DESEVT = @desc_acti,
                STSTAB = @est_acti, 
                TPGST = @tpo_gasto
            where CCIA = @compania 
            and TIPEVT = @unid_neg 
            and CODEVT = @cod_acti

        if @@ROWCOUNT = 0   
            begin   
                insert into STEVNTF(CCIA,TIPEVT,CODEVT,DESEVT,STSTAB,TPGST) 
                values(@compania,@unid_neg,@cod_acti,@desc_acti,@est_acti,@tpo_gasto)



            end
```

Comment: La consulta la ejecuto en la BDD? y en la consulta de C# pongo toda esta consulta?

Comment: @karolprincess hay que tener cuidado con esta alternativa. Puede que sean dos usuarios con información completamente distinta pero que coinciden solo en el id.

Comment: bueno eso si pero ya solucione el problema solo me dio curiosidad esta respuesta